# Laravel-5 merge multi-level form array validation

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form which I have created in Laravel-5.  This form contains input arrays.  I have also created a Request file using `php artisan make:request ClassRequest`.  Within my request file, I have added the Laravel validator() function which I use to add additional fields to the form array when the form gets posted.

However, I can't seem to get the form array updated/merged in the way that I would like.

**View file:**

```
<input type="text" name="class[0]['location_id']" value="1">
<input type="text" name="class[1]['location_id']" value="2">
```

**Request file (ClassRequest.php):**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Factory as ValidatorFactory;
use DB;

class ClassRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */

    public function validator(ValidatorFactory $factory)
    {
        $input = $this->get('class');

        foreach($input as $key => $val)
        {
            $dateInString = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $input[$key]['date']));

            $this->merge(['class' => [$key => [
                'location_id' => $input[$key]['location_id'],
                'location'  => 'test123'
                ]
            ]]);
        }

        return $factory->make($this->input(), $this->rules(), $this->messages());
    }

}
```

As you can see from the request file above, I am trying to add a new key/value pair to the form array (location => 'test123').  However, only 1 field ever gets posted through to the controller.

Does anyone know the proper way to do this?

Comment: Could you parse some more code? What is $this? What is $key? What is the desired outcome?

Comment: Sorry, this line of code is present within the validator() function in a laravel request file.

Answer (score 2):

***Merge*** function merges given array into collection and any string key in the array matching a string key in the collection will ***overwrite*** the value in the collection.So this is why you saw only 1 field posted through to controller.

```
 foreach($input as $key => $val)
        {
            $this->merge(['class' => [$key => [
                'location_id' => $input[$key]['location_id'],
                'location'  => 'test123'
                ]
            ]]);
        }
```

`'class'` key is overwritten in each iteration and only last one persist.So the only item is last one.

```
$input = $this->get('class');
foreach($input as $key => $val)
{
        $another[$key]['location_id']=$input[$key]["'location_id'"];
        $another[$key]['location']='123';
}
$myreal['class']=$another;
$this->merge($myreal);

return $factory->make($this->input(), $this->rules(), $this->messages());
```

If you are getting error related with location id then try this

```
 public function validator(ValidatorFactory $factory)
   {
    $input = $this->get('class');
    foreach($input as $key => $val)
    {
        foreach($input[$key] as $v){

            $another[$key]['location_id']=$v;
            $another[$key]['location']='124';
        }

    }
    $myreal['class']=$another;
    $this->merge($myreal);
   return $factory->make($this->input(), $this->rules(), $this->messages());
   }
```